# Decrypting objects back to original message in sha256 encoding scheme

Tags: c#, encryption, sha256

I'm designing an application where users can save data on the back end at Parse.com. But, I want the data to be encrypted as a part of the privacy policy. So say the user has a message string as "Hello World". I'm encrypting it to a hash and uploading it to Parse Object. But, when the user needs it how do I decrypt it back to his end?
Encryption code:

```
public static string getHashSha256(string text)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        string hashString = string.Empty;
        foreach (byte x in hash)
        {
            hashString += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
        }
        return hashString;
    }
```

Other possible methods to achieve same is highly appreciated. thanks

Comment: You need to understand what _hashing_ means.

Comment: SHA256 is a one-way hash. You can't "decrypt" it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: You also need key management, which is not simple.  Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: @SLaks hashing is basically creating key-value pairs with an unique identifier/key for a piece of data. That's what i knew.. Enlighten me.

Comment: No; that's a hash _table_.  (and also has nothing to do with what you want) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: @TomTom everyone has to start from somewhere, mocking people doesn't really help them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a hash function is to have a simple/fast function that can compute the hash of a string, but a very hard time to go from `hash --> string`.

You don't want SHA256 here, you want some sort of real encryption/decryption such as AES.

Comment: thanks for your advice. But then again if i decrypt then it violates privacy.. :(

Comment: So what you want is for it to be impossible to decrypt yet you want to be able to decrypt it?

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is one way, for say like passwords, where you get a password from a user, hash it and check with an already saved hash.

Encryptions can be decrypted. They are two different things.

Try AES for encryption, if you are using .NET there is AESManaged and AES Cryptoservice provider.

For govt. installations FIPS compliance of your algorithm is required. which is the cryptoserviveprovider in this case. Please check your requirements as well.

Answer (score 0):

SHA256 is the wrong way to do this.

If you want a symmetric algorithm, where you have the same key for encryption and decryption you can take a look at:

- Rijndael
- AES
- DES
- TripleDES

For an asymetric algorithm, where you have different keys for encryption and decryption, you can take a look at RSA

If you need an example, just let me/us know

Comment: Of that list the choice is simple: AES. The practical problem is that using encryption properly is hard, even when you chose a secure primitive.